# CakePHP navigation bar View structure

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, view

In CakePHP, let's say the default.ctp just does the framing HTML, with `<body>` containing `$content_for_layout` only.  This is great for most pages of `mysite.com`.  However, let's say the views within `mysite.com/account/` need to share a navigation bar.  Which would be the proper approach for the views under the account area?

A) Make the nav bar its own element, and this element is included in each view:

```
<!-- settings.ctp, profile.ctp, myfiles.ctp ... -->
<div id="account_area">
    <?php echo $this->element('account_nav'); }
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

What I don't really like in A) is that each .ctp duplicates the same wrapping code (however minimal).  So perhaps something like B) is better:

B) Create a view `account/index.ctp` and have each action set a `$section` variable and do `$this->render('/account/index')`, placing each screen in its own element:

```
<!-- /views/account/index.ctp -->
<div id="account_area">
    <div id="account_nav">...</div>
    <?php echo $this->element("account/$section"); }
</div>
```

C) Something else

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the way I do this is *Option A*. But I put the `$this->element('account_nav');` in the layout. This prevents putting the code in every view.

If the navigation requires configuration or disabling, just add logic to the layout and pass variables to the view as you would normally. Then you can configure it from any action if needed.

In the end, it's a hybrid approach. But from my experience provides the greatest flexibility.

Comment: Thanks.  Is Option B also considered a valid approach?  My app has quite a few views that need this sort of functionality in one way or another, and it might be a whole lot of display logic to put up in the layout itself.

Comment: Sure. But IMO, anytime I use `render()` I feel dirty :) From your description, it seemed like Option B required more setup.

Answer (score 0):

I am *very* new to CakePHP so I don't know what specific benefits A and B might bring, but it seems like if you want to reuse the same nav bar code in multiple views (obviously a good idea), simply (C) use PHP's include function to include the required .html or .php file?

I suppose it depends on what exactly is going in to your nav bar: anything more complex than HTML links and my idea dies quite badly. :/

Comment: Using native `include`/`require` can sever the data bridging frameworks provide. Using *elements* is the right way to do this with CakePHP.